# GridSearchCV giving score from the best estimator different from the one indicated in refit parameter

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, scoring, gridsearchcv

I am doing hyperparameter optimization using GridSearchCV

```
scoring_functions = {'mcc': make_scorer(matthews_corrcoef), 'accuracy': make_scorer(accuracy_score), 'balanced_accuracy': make_scorer(balanced_accuracy_score)}

grid_search = GridSearchCV(pipeline, param_grid=grid, scoring=scoring_functions, n_jobs=-1, cv=splitter, refit='mcc')
```

I set the refit parameter to `'mcc'` so I expect GridSearchCV to choose the best model to maximize this metric. Then I calculate some of the scores

```
preds = best_model.predict(test_df)
metrics['accuracy'] = round(accuracy_score(test_labels, preds),3)
metrics['balanced_accuracy'] = round(balanced_accuracy_score(test_labels, preds),3)
metrics['mcc'] = round(matthews_corrcoef(test_labels, preds),3)
```

And I get these results

```
"accuracy": 0.891, "balanced_accuracy": 0.723, "mcc": 0.871
```

Now if I do this to get the score of the model on the same test set (not calculating the predictions first) like this

```
best_model = grid_search.best_estimator_
score = best_model.score(test_df, test_labels)
```

The score I get is this

```
"score": 0.891
```

Which as you can see is the accuracy but not the mcc score. According to the documentation of the score function it says

> Returns the score on the given data, if the estimator has been refit.
>
> This uses the score defined by scoring where provided, and the
> best_estimator_.score method otherwise.

I don't understand correctly. I thought that if I refit the model like I specify with the refit parameter in GridSearchCV, the result should be with the scoring function used to refit the model? Am I missing something?

Comment: What kind of model is your `best_estimator_`, eg, random forest, knn...?

Comment: random forest I pass it on the pipeline with a random_state seed so the results shouldn't change

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you access the attribute `best_estimator_` you are going to the underlying base model, ignoring all the set up you have done to the `GridSearchCV` object:

```
best_model = grid_search.best_estimator_
score = best_model.score(test_df, test_labels)
```

You should use `grid_search.score()` instead and, in general, interact with that object. For example, when predicting, use `grid_search.predict()`.

The signature of those methods is the same as that of a standard Estimator (fit, predict, score, etc).

You can use the underlying model, but it won't have necessarily inherited the configuration you have done to the grid search object itself.

Comment: Ok thx, I will try it. But then what's the purpose of having the best_estimator_ object if you are not using the best estimator found during cross validation? I will report back to see if it worked. If this works it will save me a lot of extra work right now.

Comment: @Atirag the point is exactly *not* to be necessary to revert to `grid_search.best_estimator_`, and to be able to do the job at the level of the `grid_search` object itself. The `best_estimator_` is indeed used here (notice that you get the same accuracy), but its `.score` method does not know anything about other scoring methods used in `grid_search`.

Comment: When I use grid_search = GridSearchCV()  and best_model = grid_search.best_estimator_ ... and later I use predict...  What  is the model being used? The model fitted with all the training data or a model fitted at each folding and then averaged?